# How do I unit test localStorage being undefined with Mocha/Sinon/Chai

Tags: unit-testing, local-storage, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have 2 simple methods that abstract reading and writing to localStorage:

```
_readLocalStorage: function(key) {
    if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
    } else {
        throw new Error('Could not read from localStorage');
    }
},

_writeLocalStorage: function(key, data) {
    try {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Could not write to localStorage');
    }
},
```

Obviously, stubbing window.localStorage.getItem/setItem is simple. But what about the case where localStorage is undefined?

I've tried caching/unhinging window.localStorage (the second assertion):

```
describe('#_readLocalStorage', function() {
    it('should read from localStorage', function() {
        // set up
        var stub1 = sinon.stub(window.localStorage, 'getItem')
        .returns('{"foo": "bar"}');

        // run unit
        var result = service._readLocalStorage('foo');

        // verify expectations
        expect(result)
        .to.eql({foo: 'bar'});

        // tear down
        stub1.restore();
    });

    it('should throw an error if localStorage is undefined', function() {
        // set up
        var cachedLocalStorage = window.localStorage;
        window.localStorage = undefined;

        // run unit/verify expectations
        expect(service._readLocalStorage('foo'))
        .to.throw(new Error('Could not write to localStorage'));

        // tear down
        window.localStorage = cachedLocalStorage;
    });
});
```

This does not work however. Mocha/Chai seem not to catch the thrown error.

I've looked around a bit but can't find any way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `expect` should be

```
expect(service._readLocalStorage.bind(service, 'foo'))
    .to.throw(new Error('Could not write to localStorage'));
```

The way you have it you code calls `service._readLocalStorage('foo')` *before* `expect` is called. So it raises an exception that `expect` cannot handle. What `expect` needs to be able to deal with exceptions is a *function* that `expect` *itself* will call. Using `service._readLocalStorage.bind(service, 'foo')` creates a new function that when called without arguments (as `expect` does) will be equivalent to calling `service._readLocalStorage('foo')`.

There's another problem with your test: your cleanup code will never execute. The assertion libraries report problems by raising JavaScript exceptions. So any code that follows a failed exception won't run unless the exception is specially handled. You could do:

```
it('should throw an error if localStorage is undefined', function() {
    // set up
    var cachedLocalStorage = window.localStorage;
    window.localStorage = undefined;

    // run unit/verify expectations
    try {
        expect(...)...;
        expect(...)...;
        ...
    }
    finally {
        // tear down
        window.localStorage = cachedLocalStorage;
    }
});
```

For more complex cases, you should use `before`, `beforeEach`, `after`, `afterEach` for setup and teardown.

Comment: DERP, of course I can't call the cleanup code after an exception is thrown. Thanks for your answer, that works perfectly.